# What exactly is Nanoha's "dead" expression?

Tags: nanoha

According to [this Wikia page](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Media), where it discusses the difference between TV and DVD:

> One of the most notable differences is the change of Nanoha's infamous "dead" expression when casting Crossfire Shoot on Teana in StrikerS to a more disappointed one.

When I bought the DVD Set which had all 3 series and the 2 movies from eBay, I assumed it was the proper Japanese DVDs. However, given how often the subtitles change fonts and how the translation of the names and terminologies changes in later episodes, it's obvious the seller made the copies from fansubs.

That being said, I am unsure if the episode I saw were ones from the DVD release or the Japanese television release.

So I am wondering, what is Nanoha's "dead" expression? How does it compare to her disappointed one? And why would it be changed?

Comment: `how repeated name is different in later episodes` Not sure what you mean here. (Not really important to the question, though).

Comment: About the topic, a comment this blog post seems to reveal something about it, though I don't really understand, since I don't watch this series: http://kurogane.animeblogger.net/2007/05/21/nanoha-white-devil-mode/

Comment: @nhahtdh The name thing is almost certainly in reference to Nanoha's device name: Raging Heart versus Raising Heart. The official subs start with one (raising, I think), and switch to the other one. Raging was the most popular amongst fans, though I believe the Raising is officially correct.

Comment: @nhahtdh what i was referring to was when Fate is first introduced it's neither Fate not Feito in the subs but something else which just looks incorrect but then is corrected in alter episodes, i knew Fate's name before hand and what i saw it i thought "wait, how could official subs get it so wrong?" there are other instances but that's the one which mainly stuck to me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See this image:

[image: the difference between TV and DVD]

The image consists of comparison shots between the TV broadcast (left) and the DVDs (right). Except for the bottom right one, obviously. The rest are legitimate images.

This is the infamous white devil scene from *StrikerS*, and you shouldn't have much trouble noticing significant differences in the faces, especially in Nanoha's.

The severity of the difference should also suggest why it was changed: they decided Nanoha's reaction and characterization in that scene were inappropriately grim and harsh. In the broadcast, she is mortified into brutality. In the DVDs, she is disappointed but cool and in control.

Comment: you sure the third one on the left isn't fake, i don't remember [Tiida Lanster](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Tiida_Lanster) looking like [Suzaku Kururugi](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Suzaku), though if it isn't fake that might just prove the fan subs i did saw were on the TV version and i mistook Nanoha's "dead" expression as being disappointed and was expecting something else (though i do remember Nanoha's hand bleeding blocking Teana's attack)

Comment: @Memor-X I believe it is legit, though I do not have video copies of each version to verify. I wanted a version without the joke image, so that we wouldn't be suspicious of chicanery elsewhere, but did not find it.